# How to calculate percentile of score along z axis of 3d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, scipy

I'm trying to calculate percentiles using `scipy.stats.percentileofscore()` along the z axis of a 3d numpy array, with the scores in a 2d array.

For example, my 3d array might look like this:

```
data = array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],
   [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],
   [[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]])
```

And the scores to calculate percentiles for might look like this:

```
scores = array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  2.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  2.]])
```

I want to apply `percentileofscore()` at each location (m,n) in this way:

```
percentileofscore(data[:,m,n], scores[m,n])
```

The result would be this:

```
array([[ 33.33,  33.33,  66.66],
   [ 33.33,  33.33,  66.66],
   [ 33.33,  33.33,  66.66]])
```

I can do this with nested loops, but am applying this to large arrays so would like a more optimized approach. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a nested loop by reshaping your array. I think in order to avoid loops completely you will have to write a custom percentile function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

x = 3
y = 3
z = 3

d = a.reshape(z, x*y)

scores_d = scores.reshape(x*y,1)

percentiles_d = [percentileofscore(d[:, i], scores_d[i]) for i in range(x*y)]
percentiles_d = np.round(np.array(percentiles_d), 2).reshape(x,y)
print(percentiles_d)

[[ 33.33  33.33  66.67]
 [ 33.33  33.33  66.67]
 [ 33.33  33.33  66.67]]
```

Comment: This is similar to what I've already done. I would like to do it without looping over rows and columns.

Comment: The updated answer cuts loop nesting. Because you want to use different scores and they have to be fed in a function that accepts only one array and one score you probably can't avoid the single loop.